# Macro is filling only one cell, not ending when it should

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a sub/macro that, given a list of Actors with a Quota and a list of Places with a Availability, will allocate the Actors to the Places where they are Available in such a way that their Quota is met. I have dummied this system with a simpler example that should account for the common corner cases and the sources of most "universe breaker" issues if applied to the real data.

I attempt to do so by prioritising first those Actors who have the lowest current number of allocations, and from them, the Actors with the lowest quota. The intent of this priority is

- prevent one Actor allocated to all the "early" Places and one Actor allocated to all the "late" Places, purely based on where they appeared in the original list of Actors, and
- prevent Actors with a low Quota from being allocated to a Place when that Place already has many other Actors allocated to it

I start with two simple lists. In List 1, the Count column is initially zero and updated when the Actor is allocated to another Place. In List 2, the Available column is the known Availability for each Place (initially a string of the Actor names)(this is currently manual and will be automated separately) and the Allocation column is the growing string of Actors allocated to that Place (initially an empty list).

List 1. located in the range A1:C6.

```
Actor Quota Count
AA     3     0
BB     4     0
CC     4     0
DD     4     0
EE     6     0
```

List 2, located in the range A10:A21,D10:E21 (columns B and C contain other information about the Places).

```
Place Avail Alloc
 1     AABBDD
 2     AACCEE
 3     CCEE
 4     BBEE
 5     BBEE
 6     AACCDD
 7     AACC
 8     BBEE
 9     BBEE
10     CC
11     AACCDDEE
12     AABBDD
```

The code below is what I have developed so far. In theory:

1. if the Actor with highest priority has a Quota equal to their Count, do nothing (and implicitly, go to the next Actor in the list).
2. if the Actor with highest priority that passed the first test has a place in the "Available" column, increment the Actor's Count by 1, then add the Actor's name to the "Allocation" column, and remove the Actor's name from the "Available" column. Otherwise do nothing (and implicitly, go to the next Actor in the list).
3. Sort List 1 according to the priorities mentioned earlier.
4. Go to the next Place, repeat steps 1, 2, 3.
5. Repeat steps 1, 2, 3, 4 for a total of five times (to ensure the macro will process the longest possible string of availability).

   ```
   Sub FakeItUntilYouMakeIt()
   Dim m As Integer, n As Integer, i As Integer, p As Integer
   For m = 1 To 5
       For n = 10 To 21
           For i = 2 To 6
           If Cells(i, 2) > Cells(i, 3) Then
               If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), Cells(n, 4), 1) <> 0 Then
                   p = Cells(i, 3)
                   Cells(i, 3).Value = p + 1
                   Cells(n, 5).Value = Cells(n, 5) & Cells(i, 1)
                   Cells(n, 4).Replace what:=Cells(i, 1), replacement:=""
                   Range("A1:C6").Select
                   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
                   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C6"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B6"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
                       .SetRange Range("A1:C6")
                       .Header = xlYes
                       .MatchCase = False
                       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                       .Apply
                   End With
           End If
           End If
           Next i
       Next n
   Next m
   End Sub
   ```

When I run the sub/macro, I get the sheet shown in the screenshot below. In particular,

- cell E10 is filled with a nonsense combination of the Actors, possibly because it is adding **all** Allocations to that Place instead of where they should
- List 1 is sorted by Quota, lowest first
- List 1 finishes with the Count column entries all exactly 1 less than the Quota column entries
- if the sub/macro is run a second time, nothing changes, except that the Count column entries all increment by 1 and become equal to the Quota column entries

What is causing the sub/macro to fixate on cell E10, and apparently try to add every allocation to that Place? I believe it is something to do with the looping; perhaps it is not properly handling the exception where the Actor with highest priority is not in the Available string for that Place?

[image: an Excel screenshot of the results when running the above code from the given information]

Comment: The code you attached it is not working as you describe as the initial condition is to prioritize by quota. Besides, the condition it is not until you reach 0 instead when the places asigned are minor than the one not still asigned. What are you interested? In your original description or just fix your code?

Comment: I think this `InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), Cells(n, 4), 1) <> 0` should be turned around: `InStr(1, Cells(n, 4), Cells(i, 1), 1) <> 0`

Comment: The code is subject to the priorities and goal - the first two paragraphs plus the bullet points. If there is an issue like ndreisg pointed out and fixing it solves everything, then I'm okay with that; if I need to rearrange the code or use some additional steps or rethink the structure, then that's more work but still okay. @DavidGarcíaBodego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's Documentation of the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function), the second argument should be the string being searched and the third argument should be the string being sought.

So `InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), Cells(n, 4), 1) <> 0` should be `InStr(1, Cells(n, 4), Cells(i, 1), 1) <> 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

For i = 2 To 6
    k = 0
    For j = 10 To 21
        If InStr(1, Cells(j, 4).Value, Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            k = k
        Else
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
    Cells(i, 4) = k
Next i
```

With this code, you will get a new column that will return the current number of allocations for one actor. That one is your first priority. The remaining depends on your strategy... You can just take the first actor by number of allocations (less allocations) and allocate by early to late places (it is not clear for me what you consider early or late) until the quota becomes 0:

```
Dim Min As Long
Dim lookupvalue As Variant
Dim Totalrange As Range

Set Totalrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D6")
Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Totalrange)
lookupvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Min, Totalrange, 1, False) + 1

For i = 10 To 21
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, 4).Value, Cells(lookupvalue, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            i = i
        Else
            If Cells(lookupvalue, 2).Value > 0 Then
                Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value & Cells(lookupvalue, 1).Value
                Cells(lookupvalue, 2).Value = Cells(lookupvalue, 2).Value - 1
                Cells(lookupvalue, 3).Value = Cells(lookupvalue, 3).Value + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

This loop will place place the actor in location until the quota becomes 0. If that one is you strategy, you just need to place a second loop that includes this one in order to check all the actors and a sort instruction once that the i loop is finish, so when you look for the minimun value, the next interaction will not include the previous items already placed. This loop is setting actor DD as that one is the one with less number of allocations